# npm: not found when setting up Jenkins Server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jenkins, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration

This is my first time setting up a jenkins server.  The build is using Amazon's EC2 and Ubuntu 14.04.

I've installed [node](http://nodejs.org/) and [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) via [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

```
node -v
>v0.11.14

npm -v
>2.0.0
```

The repo pulls down just fine into my `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/morningharwood` folder.

**Problem: When I add my script it breaks**

Here's my build script which errors out?  *I have no idea what i'm doing.  I copied this from a tutorial.*

[image]

**QUESTION:**  How do I properly write my script to `npm install`, `bower install` and lastly, `grunt test`

Answer (score 0):

You could install node, npm, bower and grunt by doing following:

```
sudo apt-get install node
sudo npm install bower
sudo npm install grunt
```

To install a package from local source, use

```
npm install /path
```

Comment: Thats fine but I still need to do an npm install on the local package that i'm pulling from github?

Answer (score 0):

Try using NodeJS plugin for Jenkins: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

This will solve npm command not found issue on jenkins even installed on server

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/nvm
export NVM_DIR=/usr/local/nvm

curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh |NVM_DIR=/usr/local/nvm bash

. /usr/local/nvm/nvm.sh
nvm install 10.15.3 -g
npm install @angular/cli -g
```

Include following on build execute shell command in jenkins:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin"
npm install
```